# Unable to extract object from single-item numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I seem to be hitting a wall on what is likely a very simple issue to solve.  I have saved out a *.npz file containing a single variable--an object of class Network (a class I wrote).

```
# Initialize network 
burstNetwork = Network(numChs,dt,UFRs,NBPs,BDs,UFRsByChan,varyFRbyChs,minChConstBurst,createChCorrelations)
if saveData:
    pd.np.savez((saveDir + "simulator.npz"), burstNetwork=burstNetwork)
```

When I try to read the data back in, I find that my variable is now in the form of an numpy array of size 1 that I am unable to index from, and thus unable to get my Network object back and view its attributes (my end goal).

```
# Load network
simulator = np.load(simFilesDir + "simulator.npz")
network = simulator['burstNetwork']
network

Out[43]: array(<__main__.Network object at 0x000000000AEF0C18>, dtype=object)
```

Indexing attempt:

```
network[0]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-297be643431d> in <module>()
----> 1 network[0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When indexing an array you need a tuple that matches the dimensions in length.  This is 0d, so the tuple has to be 0 length, `()`.  The `item` method also works.

```
In [922]: arr = np.array(1, dtype=object)
In [923]: arr.shape
Out[923]: ()
In [924]: arr
Out[924]: array(1, dtype=object)
In [925]: arr.item()
Out[925]: 1
In [926]: arr[()]
Out[926]: 1
```